# Using SVGMarker inplace of default symbol using in point vector layer

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, pyqgis-3, svg, vector-layer

I am trying to use the SVGmarker symbol for displaying the point vector layer. I was able to change the default symbol for the point vector layer. but I am not getting an idea of using the SVGmarker symbol in place of the default symbol. I am using QGIS3 C++ APIs.Even any lead in python will be beneficial.
for example :

path for SVGmarker symbol:**"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\svg\food\food_bar.svg"**

code snipped for changing vector layer symbol:

```
    layer->startEditing();
    qDebug()<< "is editable " << layer->isEditable();
    QgsFeatureRenderer * layerRenderer= layer->renderer();
    QgsSingleSymbolRenderer *mSingleRenderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer::convertFromRenderer(layerRenderer);
    QgsMarkerSymbol* symbol = new  QgsMarkerSymbol();
    QgsStringMap mp;
    mp[QString("fill")]= QString("red");
    mp[QString("name")]= QString("food_bar.svg");
    mp[QString("size")]= QString("6");
    mp[QString("outline")]=QString("black");
    mp[QString("outline-width")]=QString("6.8");
    auto svgsymbol = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer::create(mp);
    auto newsym=     symbol->createSimple(mp);
    mSingleRenderer->setSymbol(newsym);
    layer->setRenderer(mSingleRenderer);
    layer->triggerRepaint();
    layer->commitChanges();
    qDebug()<< "is editable after commiting  " << layer->isEditable();
```

In the above code, I am not able to provide a path of  food_bar.svg icon. color and size are getting changed. but the icon is not coming.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. Here is the code snipped

```
        layer->startEditing();
        qDebug()<< "is editable " << layer->isEditable();
        QgsFeatureRenderer * layerRenderer= layer->renderer();
        QgsSingleSymbolRenderer *mSingleRenderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer::convertFromRenderer(layerRenderer);
        QgsMarkerSymbol* symbol = new  QgsMarkerSymbol();
        QgsStringMap mp;
       // mp[QString("fill")]= QString("red");
        mp[QString("name")]= QString("food_pub.svg");
        mp[QString("size")]= QString("6");
      //  mp[QString("outline")]=QString("black");
     //   mp[QString("outline-width")]=QString("6.8");

        QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer svglayer("C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis-ltr-dev\\svg\\food\\food_pub.svg");
        QgsSymbolLayer* svgsymbol=svglayer.create(mp);
       auto newsym=     symbol->createSimple(mp);
       newsym->changeSymbolLayer(0,svgsymbol);
       mSingleRenderer->setSymbol(newsym);
        layer->setRenderer(mSingleRenderer);
        layer->triggerRepaint();
        layer->commitChanges();
        qDebug()<< "is editable after commiting  " << layer->isEditable();
```